# How to free an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, free

I have a struct `complex` and a struct `complex_set` (a set of complex numbers) and I have the "constructor" and "destructor" functions `alloc_set` and `free_set`.

My problem is, that I get the following error in the second iteration of the for loop in `free_set`:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1001054f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

What is the correct way to deinitialize `complex_set`? I'm wondering whether the `*points` property of `complex_set` needs to be freed only by calling `free` on the first point (and then it will free the rest) or by freeing each element separately? Or have I already done something wrong in the initialisation?

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct complex complex;
typedef struct complex_set complex_set;

struct complex { double a; double b; };
struct complex_set {
    int num_points_in_set;
    complex *points; // an array of struct complex
};

struct complex_set *alloc_set(complex c_arr[], int size) {
    complex_set *set = (complex_set *) malloc(sizeof(complex_set));
    set->num_points_in_set = size;
    // i think i may even just use the pointer c_arr as '*points'
    // however, i want to make sure malloc was called
    set->points = (complex *) malloc(size*sizeof(complex));
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        set->points[i] = c_arr[i];
    }
    return set;
}

void free_set(complex_set *set) {
    complex *current = set->points;
    complex *next = NULL;
    int iterations = set->num_points_in_set;
    for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        next = current + 1;
        // i get the error here, in the second iteration:
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
    free(set);
    set = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You must have one `free` for each `malloc`. In your allocation you have exactly two `malloc`s, but in your free you call `free` many times. Fix this up

Comment: Thanks! So for an array of structs we only have to call free once (on the pointer to the beginning).

Comment: You call `free` once for each time you called `malloc` once, there's no plainer way to say it really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only did one `malloc()` for `set->points`, so you should only do one `free()`.

You're trying to free each point.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:
     `free(set->points);`

Comment: I see that this is the correct solution - but it doesn't explain why.